# Is there a way to get a specific QLabel when they overlap in a QGridLayout?

Tags: pyqt5, qgridlayout

In PyQt5, I'm using a QGridLayout to organize some widgets. I want to overlap a QLabel over another, in order to put a PixMap underneath and later drag anotherone an put it on top.

However, I'd like to later access just the label on top in order to clear it or manipulate it in another way, but I don't know how I can call just that one.

I'd like something like the `QGridLayout.itemAtPosition(row, column)` method, but just to manipulate the last label I added.

Here's what I want in more depth:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QGridLayout, QLabel)

import sys

class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_gui()

    def init_gui(self):

        self.setGeometry(500, 500, 500, 500)

        grid = QGridLayout()

        label_1 = QLabel("behind", self)
        label_2 = QLabel("TOP", self)

        grid.addWidget(label_1, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(label_2, 0, 0)

        # Here, I want to get a reference just to label_2, but this returns a QWidgetItem type.
        grid.itemAtPosition(0, 0)

        # With this, I would like to then maybe update the label or its content.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    form = Window()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: You can't. `itemAtPosition()` will always return a single QLayoutItem, and that will be the first item inserted for that row/column combination. Assuming that you're always going to put those two widgets in a single layout cell (no spanning), what you could do is to create a custom widget that acts as a container and includes the two labels, without any layout management, and overriding their `minimumSizeHint()` that would return the largest size between them. Then it's just a matter to access that widget and get its "top" or "bottom" widget.

Comment: That said, I'm curious: why are you doing this? Are you trying to do some sort of "icon viewer"? If that's the case, you should consider other alternatives, such as a QListView with a custom model and item delegate.

Comment: I'm doing like a grid where you can put images, but you can then move them. So I wanted to fix a standard background and over it put the pixmaps. Later, I wanted to get the pixmap info and manipulate it. I'd be very thankful if you could offer me some alternatives :)

Comment: Well, layout managers are usually intended for "static" purposes. Their main objective is to provide "responsive" layout that provides a reliable and consistent UI. While it's not impossible to make them "interactive" (for instance, with drag&drop features), that's really not the way they are intended to work. Furthermore, you're talking about the possibility of "moving" items, and that cannot be really done with layout managers, especially QGridLayout, which has an important limit, being that its row and column count is **not** "dynamically" reliable: they can only grow, but never shrink.

Comment: If you add layout items (widgets, spacers or child layouts) and then remove them, the row/column count will **not** decrease based on the contents. That might not be ideal, but you also need to remember that it's not the purpose of a Qt layout manager. If you want to put *movable* items in a grid (similarly to a file manager), you have to look for different solutions: as already suggested, a QListView may be a valid choice, but the Graphics View framework provides an even more flexible (though complex) API. In any case, if you want a "dynamic file browser" UI, QGridLayout is not the solution.

Comment: I see... I will definitely consider those things. Thank you!